# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)

Tags: reactjs

[This is an Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwnP1.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pREYX.png)After 5 months I run my react portfolio. Then this error occurred.

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
D:\Portfolio\Malsha_Dissanayaka-Portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

Node.js v18.17.1